# Angular2: Up-to-date simple form example? (Feb 2016)

Tags: forms, typescript, angular

**Q) Can someone please expand this snippet so that I can get it to work?**

I've tried a few different form tutorials and they all differ and none seem to work.  I don't understand why `_fb: FormBuilder` isn't being loaded/causing "*unexpected token < error*"

Here's my basic app:

**formExample.component.ts:**

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {OnInit} from 'angular2/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'form-example',
  template: `
    <h3>Form Example</h3>
    <form [ngFormModel]="testForm" (submit)="checkValues($event)">
      <input ngControl="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  `
})


export class FormExampleComponent {

  constructor(private _fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.testForm = _fb.group({
      name: ["", Validators.required]
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  checkValues(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = this.testForm.value;
    alert(name);
  }

}
```

**main.ts:**

```
import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser'
import {AppComponent} from './app.component'
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/http';


bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS
]);
```

Comment: Have you tried the [Angular 2 official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html)?

Comment: Yes, no joy. I just want my above example to load so I can enter a value and see the alert when I submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include a reference to FormBuilder and Validators:

```
import {FormBuilder, Validators} from 'angular2/common';
```

If you've included references to `Http`, then make sure to include the script tag:

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>
```

Comment: Done that in the formExampleComponent and get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token <"

Comment: usually the unexpected token '<' is caused by Http returning invalid json. try checking the URL in a browser to make sure its not returning an error.

Comment: Yeah this is the error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
 Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2/http
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js

But I don't understand: this page isn't doing any HTTP requests.

Comment: did you add the script tag?     <script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script>

Comment: Ok, I got it, needed to add Validators too and restart the npm start command